# How to capture return code for subprocess.check_call in Python

Tags: python, subprocess

I have a script that is executing 5 different shell commands and I'm using `subprocess.check_call()` to execute them. The problem is that I can't seem to figure out how to properly capture and analyze the return code.

According to the docs `The CalledProcessError object will have the return code in the returncode attribute.`, but I don't understand how to access that. If I say

```
rc = subprocess.check_call("command that fails")
print(rc)
```

It tells me

> subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command 'command that fails' returned non-zero exit status 1

But I can't figure out how to capture just the integer output of 1.

I'd imagine this must be doable somehow?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `check_call` you'll have to add a try/except block and access the exception. With `subprocess.run` you can access the result without a try/except block.

```py
import subprocess

try:
    subprocess.check_call(["command", "that", "fails"])
except subprocess.CalledProcessError as e:
    print(e.returncode)
```

Or using `subprocess.run`:

```py
result = subprocess.run(["command", "that", "fails"])
print(result.returncode)
```

Comment: I was missing the `as e:` bit, that explains it perfectly. Thanks to you and @MindOfMetalAndWheels for the help.

Answer (score 1):

Whenever the `subprocess.check_call` method fails is raises a `CalledProcessError`. From the docs:

> `subprocess.check_call(args, *, stdin=None, stdout=None, stderr=None, shell=False, cwd=None, timeout=None, **other_popen_kwargs)`
>
> Run command with arguments. Wait for command to complete. If the
>   return code was zero then return, otherwise raise CalledProcessError.
>   The CalledProcessError object will have the return code in the
>   returncode attribute.

You may just want subprocess.run or to use a try/except block to handle the CalledProcessError

perhaps

```
rc = subprocess.run("some_cmd").returncode
```

or

```
try
...
    rc = subprocess.check_call("command that fails")
except CalledProcessError as error:
    rc = error.returncode
```

Comment: I'm currently using a `try/except` actually, but when I try to say `except CalledProcessorerror` and then say `print rc` in that block, it tells me `rc` hasn't been assigned yet.

Comment: it says `rc` hasn't been assigned because the `CalledProcessError` object has the return code, the `check_call` didn't assign to `rc` because it raised an exception

Comment: except CalledProcessError as e: print(e.returncode)